# Distance measurement methods used in Hierarchical Clustering

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, hierarchical-clustering

In Hierarchical Clustering, what are the distance measurement methods used? Are different measurement methods used depending on the purpose?

If performing Hierarchical Clustering for Region Proposal, please let me know which distance measurement method is typically used. Thank you.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/ might be a better forum for this